# (python GUI)I think This is an efficient code, but there has a grammatical error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I wrote a program that moves the hexagon shape by the number of times.
There is an error on Line 8, but I'm asking you if there are any errors on the other line,

```
import time
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=1000, background="black")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(300,200,300,250,340,225,fill="yellow")

def TKUptake(CanvasMove(x),CanvasMove(y),CanvasMove(z)):
for x in range(0, 20):
    canvas.move(CanvasMove(x),CanvasMove(y),CanvasMove(z))
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)

k = int(input("input value"))
for q in range(0,k):    
   TKUptake(1,5,5)
   TKUptake(1,5,5)
   TKUptake(1,-5,5)
   TKUptake(1,-5,0)
   TKUptake(0,-5,-5)
   TKUptake(0,5,-5)
```

Comment: What is `CanvasMove`? This doesn't seem to be a method that exists. Why not do `def TKUptake(x, y, z)` and `canvas.move(x, y, z)`

Comment: grammatical error ???

Answer (score 0):

line number 8 has indentation error, fix it by using the following

```
def TKUptake(CanvasMove(x),CanvasMove(y),CanvasMove(z)):
    for x in range(0, 20):
        canvas.move(CanvasMove(x),CanvasMove(y),CanvasMove(z))
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.03)
```

Comment: um.. Thanks very much for your help...It was my mistake that I made by mistranslating here. So it was not an indentation error. Python says this is a grammatical error.

Comment: Hi @LinuxUbuntu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.